# How to get list of bookmarks and hide bookmarks from Report?

Tags: powerbi-embedded

My report has several bookmarks. Is there any way that I could get list of all the bookmarks in my report ?

Also how could I hide my bookmarks, if needed. I tried this code but it's not working

```
    let embedConfig = {
          ...
          bookmarks: {
           visible: false
          }
    };
```

[image]

Comment: This code is very old. With the current version of the client you should use `panes` property, as show in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/configure-report-settings#panes).

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of bookmarks, follow the below code snippet -

1. Get a reference to the `HTML` element that contains the embedded report:

```js
const embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];
```

2. Embed the `report`:

```js
const report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, embedConfig);
```

3. Use `forEach` to loop through the `bookmark` collection.

```js
const bookmarks = await report.bookmarksManager.getBookmarks();
    bookmarks.forEach(function (bookmark) {
        const bookmarkData = bookmark.name + " - " + bookmark.displayName;
        console.log(bookmarkData);
    });
```

To hide the bookmarks pane, follow the below code snippet -

```js
const embedConfig = {
…
    settings:{
        panes: {
            bookmarks: {
                visible: false
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Please refer the following :
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/report-bookmarks#get-a-list-of-saved-report-bookmarks
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/configure-report-settings#panes